# Open boostrap Modal and load corresponding values from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 3 buttons(tiles) created through ng-repeat looping through a jason file. When clicking on the button, I want a boostrap modal to display the corresponding number of sub_task in buttons(tiles) inside the modal.

How can I pass the "id" of the button i'm clicking so that it will load the correct amount of buttons inside the modal?

JSON example

```
{
"tasklist": [
    {"task": 1,"sub_task": 4},
    {"task": 2,"sub_task": 3},
    {"task": 3,"sub_task": 6}
    ]
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

PS: Here a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/5TyLGEuJ2wTn3XkQpDNU/)

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: you can pass id through ng-click() function with that you can do whatever yo want and yes i agree with @Matty need to check version also first ,can you post your code here if included with any api calls then add even dummy data so that i can tell you...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, i'm using bootstrap 3.3.6 and angular 1.4
and i've added a plunker in my post :)
I've scraped the json and added the data into the controller for simplification.